# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app : cannot sign out

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I cannot sign out and my `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` still shows "true" even after the `logout` action is executed.

My `Program.cs` file is like this

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate()
   .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
   {
       options.Cookie.Name = "Test";
       options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
   });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

And the `Logout` action is like this:

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
    {
        var siteCookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies
                                             .Where(c => c.Key.Contains(".AspNetCore.") 
                                                         || c.Key.Contains("Microsoft.Authentication"));

        foreach (var cookie in siteCookies)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
        }
    }

    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    HttpContext.Session.Clear();

    HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()));

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes issues arise due to browser caching problems or failure to delete cookies. You should ensure that browser cookies are cleared after the `HttpContext.SignOutAsync` call.

Your cookie clearing process in the code appears as follows:

```
if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
{
    var siteCookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(c => c.Key.Contains(".AspNetCore.") || c.Key.Contains("Microsoft.Authentication"));
    foreach (var cookie in siteCookies)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
    }
}
```

This code seems to delete cookies containing `.AspNetCore.` or `Microsoft.Authentication`. However, you should ensure that the cookies are correctly deleted. Instead, you can try using the following code to delete all cookies:

```
foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
}
```

Additionally, instead of assigning an empty identity to `HttpContext.User`, it is expected that `HttpContext.User` gets automatically updated with an empty identity after the `HttpContext.SignOutAsync` call. Therefore, you can remove the line `HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()));`.

By making these changes, you can verify your Logout process and check if the session logout operates as expected.